# How to match extracted spots from star image to star catalog

Tags: python, pattern-matching, cluster-analysis, astropy, astronomy

I have used https://photutils.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ to extract star spots from my FITS image, which is relatively easy and neatly managed in python.
Now I want to match extracted "possible" stars from my image to a stars from the catalog to get star RA DEC coordinates of every pixel.
Has anyone done this already in python?
Or has some instructions?

Comment: I tried astrometry.net, but it doesn't exactly fits my needs.
It is rather slow(my requirement for solving is 2 sec).
Astronomy.net is more or less blind solver, but I know roughly where my camera is pointing and what is  my FOV.
I need highly customizable program to be able to mask some background in image, to mask part of the view where I don't expect to find any sources.
Also, I want to calculate an error of the estimate.

Comment: You can also use Astropy: https://docs.astropy.org/en/latest/coordinates/matchsep.html#astropy-coordinates-matching

Comment: That particular method is finding the minimum distance from the extracted source(which already has RADEC coordinates) to a star from the catalog.
I don't have RA DEC of my sources, only pixel location on the image.
And the purpose of this task is by matching image star to star from the catalog to identify RADEC coordinate of every pixel.

Comment: Sorry, I missed that. You may be interested in registration packages such as https://github.com/dstndstn/astromalign or https://github.com/rlwastro/robust-registration

Comment: Once you do match a couple stars' positions, you can fit a WCS with https://docs.astropy.org/en/stable/api/astropy.wcs.utils.fit_wcs_from_points.html, but the original matching is definitely the hard part.  How roughly do you know your pointing?

Comment: @keflavich I will try again with astrometry. First detect sources with photutils, mask background and then forward edited image to astromety.
I am around 5 deg certain about my camera pointing.

Answer (score 0):

You can download, build and run the astrometry.net code locally

https://astrometrynet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/build.html

http://astrometry.net/doc/readme.html#tricks-and-tips

The solve-field program has optional parameters that speed up the search

```
SOLVE-FIELD(1)                  astrometry.net                  SOLVE-FIELD(1)

NAME
       solve-field - Main high-level command-line user interface.

SYNOPSIS
       solve-field  [options]  [image-file-1  image-file-2  ...]  [xyls-file-1
       xyls-file-2 ...]

[...]

   -3 RA, --ra RA
          RA of field center for search, format: degrees or hh:mm:ss

   -4 DEC, --dec DEC
          DEC of field center for search, format: degrees or hh:mm:ss

   -5 degrees, --radius degrees
          Only search in indexes within 'radius' of the field center given
          by --ra and --dec

   -d, --depth number or range
          Number  of  field  objects to look at, or range of numbers; 1 is
          the brightest star, so "-d 10" or "-d 1-10" mean look at the top
          ten brightest stars only.

   --objs int
          Cut  the  source list to have this many items (after sorting, if
          applicable).

[...]

   -z, --downsample int
          Downsample the image by factor int before running source extraction
```